# Menu items not showing up properly as a mega menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I need to make a mega menu similar to one as show in image below
[image]

So far i have been able to make it work to some extent example on [jsFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4RFtc/).

So far i have some design issue and one functionality issue.

When i try to hide the default text for each dropdown menu `//$(this).find(".nav-info").hide();` then  Menu 4 & 5 doesnt  show up on right side.

I am actually trying to create a menu similar to one as on this [website](http://www.hlgroup.com/en/section/capabilities).
One this website they also show a default text for parent menu which i dont need actually.

I modified script to show the first li of submenu it works find for Parent menu ONE, TWO but creates alighnment problem for MENU FOUR and FIVE.

I would appreciate if some can help me fix this issue...

CODE

```
<div class="container_16">
    <div class="nav-main grid_16">
        <div class="wrap-nav-media">
            <ul id="nav-top-media">
                <!-- ONE -->
                <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="..company-overview">Parent Menu One</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../directors" rel="sub-1-relative-1">sub-1-relative-1</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../management-team" rel="sub-1-relative-2">sub-1-relative-2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last"><a class="current" href="../tems.html" rel="sub-1-relative-3">sub-1-relative-3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: block;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-1-relative-1">    <a href="../board-of-directors" title="Board of Directors" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-1-relative-1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: block;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-1-relative-2">  <a href="../management-team" title="Management Team" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow; float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-1-relative-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-1-relative-3">   <a href="../vision.html" title="Vision" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-1-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- TWO -->
                <li class="nav-item-2"> <a href="..capabilities">Parent Menu TWO</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="../infrastructure" rel="sub-2-relative-1">sub-2-relative-1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="..capabilities/building" rel="sub-2-relative-2">sub-2-relative-2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last"><a class="current" href="..capabilities/rail" rel="sub-2-relative-3">sub-2-relative-3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-2-relative-1"> <a href="../infrastructure" title="Infrastructure" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-2-relative-1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-2-relative-2">   <a href="../building" title="Building" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                    <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-2-relative-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-2-relative-3">   <a href="/rail" title="Rail" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-2-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item-3"><a href="../projects">THREE</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item-4"> <a href="../-businesses">FOUR</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <div style="display: block; float:right;" class="menu-page nav-info">   <a class="thumb" rel="nofollow" title=" Businesses" href="../businesses">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>TEXT will be here...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="">   <a class="current" href="2.html" rel="sub-4-relative-1">sub-4-relative-1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="">   <a class="current" href="1.html" rel="sub-4-relative-2">sub-4-relative-2</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-4-relative-1"> <a href="../group.html" title="" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <img src="HLG-Mega-Menu_files/20110602_1-ARG.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>TEXT will be here...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-4-relative-2">   <a href="../advance-water-and-environmentawe.html" title="Advance Water and Environment (AWE)" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <img src="HLG-Mega-Menu_files/20121024_AWG-220x165.jpg" alt="Advance Water and Environment (AWE)">
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>TEXT will be here...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="last nav-item-5"><a href="../sustainability">FIVE</a>

                    <div style="display: none;" class="inner-nav-media">
                        <div style="display: block;" class="menu-page nav-info">    <a class="thumb" rel="nofollow" title="" href="">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>This is Default text when i try to hide this then this menu moves to left</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-1">sub-5-relative-1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-2">sub-5-relative-2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-3">sub-5-relative-3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last"><a class="current" href="" rel="sub-5-relative-4">sub-5-relative-4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page first" id="mega-sub-5-relative-1"> <a href="/safety.html" title="" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-5-relative-2">   <a href="/environment.html" title="Environment" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-5-relative-3">   <a href="/community.html" title="Community" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" class="menu-page" id="mega-sub-5-relative-4">   <a href="/quality.html" title="Quality" rel="nofollow" class="thumb">
                                        <div style="height:80px width:80px; background-color:yellow;float:right;">IMAGE</div>
                                    </a>

                            <div>
                                <p>Brief Contents will show up here sub-5-relative-4</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the head of the document,

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js"></script>       
    <![endif]-->
```

And use the method suggested by Rachel Reveley.

```
li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

The code adds support for HTML 5 and CSS3 on older browsers. And it seems to be working perfect for me.

Comment: Can you give me fiddle link if you have tested it on fiddle

Comment: Thanks, i tried to make some changes but so far no luck.. http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/9/ - The ul ul ul {} needed a position: absolute; and left: 100%; in order to show the 3rd menu.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are supporting IE6 then you don't need JavaScript to make a drop down menu work.

If you change your structure to something more like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Click me</a>
        <ul>
            <li>This is showed when Click Me! is clicked.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can simply do this with your CSS

```
li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

Comment: @ I atleast need support for IE 7. and how can i then show related div next to li

Comment: Can you please show me atleast one menu as example so that i can take it from their