# Navigation menus with css not showing up properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, navigation

I am working on a navigation menu which should show next to its submenu text and image.  More like this as show in image below.

[image]

So far i am not able to get the desired results due to correct css property use.

I have setup fiddle i hope some can help me with this. i have tried several different ways & different example to make it working but it is not working so far. I have just wasted few days with it.

So i am trying to keep it simple with the one i am working on now [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/5/)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="block-right">
                        <li><div class="div-right">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[I also worked on this one but i am not able to fix it either posted two days back on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943666/menu-items-not-showing-up-properly-as-a-mega-menu).

Comment: I'm not sure you can adapt the menu items to the viewport with css only. When I have to code dropdown menus, I generally use the solution here http://danielupshaw.com/jquery-css-dropdown-plugin/readme.html - It's a jQuery based solution, has several options, and can adapt to viewport.

Comment: @MihaiAlex, this is a nice example but it doent seems to address my issue.

Comment: If you do consider using a jQuery solution, this could help you get started http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/6/ It won't work if you add another sub-item level though

Comment: @MihaiAlex, This is just shows the menu on parent menu hover and other sub menus still appear next to them i want all of them to show on top right cornet of first sub menu. Anyways thanks as this is also useful.